# what problems make traceback (win7, python-3.6.1, process, multiprocessing)

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, pid, traceback

```
In [1]: from multiprocessing import Process

In [2]: import os

In [3]: def run_proc(name):
   ...:     print('Run child process %s (%s)...' % (name, os.getpid()))
   ...: if __name__=='__main__':
   ...:     print('Parent process %s.' % os.getpid())
   ...:     p = Process(target=run_proc, args=('test',))
   ...:     print('Child process will start.')
   ...:     p.start()
   ...:     p.join()
   ...:     print('Child process end.')
   ...:
Parent process 4672.
Child process will start.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\mul
tiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\mul
tiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'run_proc' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Child process end.
```

`p = Process(target=run_proc, args=('test',))`    did not execute and made wrong
the others can be executed rightly. I do not know why

Comment: Formatted inline code.

Comment: thanks, but python need formatted inline code? And how? I do not understand clearly...isn't the upper code formatted code?

Comment: I Edited your post.

Comment: I finally figure out what the reason is. multiprocessing can't be used in python mutual environment, and it must be used in windows command. Anyway, thank you for the quick answer. really thank you very much.